# How to stop TFS Build when custom task fails

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I am calling a custom task (derived from Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task) from the AfterDropBuild target in my TFSBuild.proj. If my Execute override returns false, the build log shows the task as FAILED, but I still get a successful build, which means that I do not realise there is a problem with the build. How do I ensure that the build as a whole also fails?

Edit: This is TFS 2008.

Comment: What TFS version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've created a mismatch between logged errors and your task result.  You need to first log an error, with Log.LogError.  Then return !Log.HasLoggedErrors from your tasks, always.  (from trick #2 in the book "MSBuild Trickery").